# How to receive celery tasks from another module

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I can successfully receive celery tasks from my main app - however, my system cannot receive tasks from another module. I'm on a remote Ubuntu server using supervisor for for celery.

`draft1` is my main app and `post` is another module (the one that I can't receive tasks from).

**draft1/__init__.py**

```
#This will make sure the app is always imported when
#Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**draft1/celery.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'draft1.settings')

app = Celery("draft1", broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL, include=['post'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS) #post is in my installed apps
```

**draft1/tasks.py**

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))
def test_job():
    from polls.models import Question
    for i in Question.objects.all():
        if i.question_text == "test":
            i.question_text = "not_test"
            i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


@periodic_task(name='run_scheduled_jobs', run_every=timedelta(seconds=30))
def run_scheduled_jobs():
    return True
```

**post/tasks.py**

```
@periodic_task(name='test_post', run_every=timedelta(seconds=30))
def test_post():
    from .models import Post
    for i in Post.objects.all():
        if i.entered_category == "test":
            i.entered_category = "not_test"
            i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


@periodic_task(name='post_jobs', run_every=timedelta(seconds=30)) # task name found! celery will do its job
def post_jobs():
    # do whatever stuff you do
    return True
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'run_scheduled_jobs': {
        'task': 'run_scheduled_jobs', # the same goes in the task name
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=45),
    },
    'test_job': {
            'task': 'tasks.test_job',
            'schedule': timedelta(minutes=3),
    },
    'post_jobs': {
        'task': 'post.tasks.post_jobs',  #i've also tried tasks.post_jobs
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=1),
    },
    'test_post': {
        'task': 'post.tasks.test_post',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=45),
    }
}
```

Here is my command to start the worker: `celery -A draft1 worker -l info`

and celery beat is started via: `celery -A draft1 beat -l info --scheduler`.

The tasks from `draft1/tasks.py` are the only tasks I receive:

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The `celery -A` switch you are passing explicitly creates a worker for only the `draft1` app. You'll want a separate worker for the `post` app, as well as setting up a `celery.py` for that one to, so that you can create a separate Celery instance for the `post` tasks. These can obviously share the same message broker if you want (and you probably do).

Answer (score 0):

You need write in your module in init.py:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

Then create celery.py in same place with:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','name_project.settings')
app = Celery("name_your_django_module")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

In django settings.py:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
'name_module.file_with_tasks']


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
"name_tasks": {
    "task": "name_module.file_with_tasks.name_task_func",
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
},}
```

In my project main djanfo module name - Social_network, new module with celery - tasks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx1zZ.png